# Inserir pontos de edição bloqueando interação do usuário

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Usando a API Javascript do Google Maps, com esse código abaixo eu estou criando um `PoLyline`, que seria uma linha no mapa passando um *array* de coordenadas no `path`. Vejam:

```
Polyline maplines = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: groups[i].arrLatLng,
  strokeColor: "#"+hexColors[i],
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 3,
  zIndex: 2,
  editable: true
})
```

Eu segui o [exemplo em Simple Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple?hl=pt-br), na própria documentação do Google Maps API. Veja abaixo a representação de 2 `Polylines`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para que seja possível editar a linha aparecendo aquelas "bolinhas brancas" em cada ponto, eu defini a propriedade `editable` como `true`.

A questão é que, quero que a linha seja fixa sem interação do usuário, porém quero que as "bolinhas brancas" permaneçam. Se eu remover a propriedade `editable`, as linhas ficarão fixas, porém as "bolinhas brancas" sumirão.

Seria possível inerir os pontos de edição (bolinhas brancas) sem que o usuário possa interagir com a linha? Qual seria melhor forma de fazer isso?